# Passing variables through htaccess with a rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the following

```
http://example.com/somefile?variable=somevariable
```

to

```
index.php?processurl=/somefile?variable=somevariable
```

I understand I need to use [QSA] to pass the variables so I have written the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?processurl=/$1 [QSA]
```

However this RewriteRule doesn't seem to be passing the variable. All I get is index.php?processurl=/somefile

Comment: Try changing the / in the new Query String to %2F and see if that helps. `processurl=%2F$1` etc.

Comment: You have to add the `[L]` (Last) flag. Try `[QSA,L]`

Comment: **First**, it'd rewrite to: `index.php?processurl=/somefile&variable=somevariable` though that's irrelevant as you'd never see it. **Second**: _"All I get is index.php?processurl=/somefile"_ where is it that you get that? **Third**: Have you tried `var_dump($_GET);`? What's the output?

Comment: @Steven  **Second**: I get that when I echo `$_GET[processurl]` . **Third**: Output is `array(2) { ["loadurl"]=> string(8) "/somefile" ["variable"]=> string(12) "somevariable" }` So the rewriterule is working as it should, it is just my php that isn't taking the whole string. How can I for example `echo` all of `$_GET[processurl]`, without having to `$_GET` all the separate variables. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I've added a solution/explanation below which should solve your problem (assuming I understand what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem is with your understanding of the `QSA` flag. What that does is appends the original query string to the redirected URL. This is useful in some circumstances where you wish to append another parameter (or more than one) to the query string.

---

**Example**

Given the URL:

```
 http://example.com/?var1=somevalue
```

Then the rewrite rules:

```
 RewriteRule . /?var2=thisvalue
 RewriteRule . /?var2=thisvalue [QSA]
```

Would output:

```
 Rule 1 > http://example.com/?var2=thisvalue
 Rule 2 > http://example.com/?var2=thisvalue&var1=somevalue
```

---

The problem, in your case is that you don't want to append the query string as a query string you want to append it as a variable; if that makes sense...

**Solution**

The solution then is - as simple as it sounds - to append the query string as a variable...

You can do this with the use of the variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?processurl=/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

---

**Suggestion**

As anubhava pointed out you might like to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So that you don't accidentally wind up rewriting the wrong urls.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?processurl=/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Good to know. Just to clarify, it's: `%{Query_STRING}`

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, this solution works great however it only passes the first query in the string. Any subsequent variables in the url are ignored. How do I include them all?

Comment: Can you post an example `URL` where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?processurl=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is the `RewriteCond` are necessary? I think `[L]` should be enough?

Comment: It is necessary to avoid rewriting css/js/images files and existing directories.